# opencv-3.0.0 version is able to read an image which is unreadable by opencv-2.4.10

Tags: python, opencv, jpeg, opencv3.0, imread

I have a dataset and I want to delete all unreadable images. I tired to delete all unreadable images using python code given below, but interestingly I found that, when ran the code using opencv-3.0.0 it is able to read it. But when I tried to read same image using opencv-2.4.10 it returns 'None'.
Here is the code I used:

**Using opencv-3.0.0:**

`if cv2.imread(path_to_image) == None: 
     os.remove(path_to_image)`

**Image is not removed**

**Using opencv-2.4.10:**

`if cv2.imread(path_to_image) == None: 
     os.remove(path_to_image)`

**Image is removed**

Here the one [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwsTQ0Lxr_RnUjdPdlduSXlvR0ctbHFreFFHMlp1eFVicmFr/view?usp=sharing) that is unreadable.
Can anyone say why is this happening?

Comment: There's currently an issue raised about the differences in reading in images between the two standards.  Specifically, there are slight pixel differences between OpenCV 2.4 and OpenCV 3.0 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607731/opencv-vs-matlab-different-values-on-pixels-with-imread and also http://code.opencv.org/issues/4148 - it comes down to the actual JPEG decoder itself and that it's  different between versions... are your images JPEG?

Comment: Images in my dataset are JPEG only, but by doing `file image_name.jpg` it show file format as HTML, may be my dataset is corrupted too. Thanks for the references.