# CNN performance worse when loading data with tf.Data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.data.dataset

I have a trained `EfficientNetB2` neural network that I'm using for image classification. When I'm loading the images with `PIL` like this:

```
image = Image.open(item)
image = image.convert('RGB').resize((120, 120))
image = np.array(image)

if image.ndim == 3:
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis = 0)


predictions.append(model.predict(image))
```

I get accuracy at around 90%. This is, however, extremely slow so I tried using `tf.data` to load my dataset. This looks something like this:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(test_dir / '*' / '*'))
ds = (ds
      .map(load_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
      .cache()
      .batch(32)
        
      .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    )
```

And this is the `load_data` function:

```
def load_image_and_label(file_path):
   label = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.sep)[-2]
   image = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
   image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3, dct_method='INTEGER_ACCURATE')
   image = tf.image.resize(image, target_size)
   

   return image, label
```

This is, as expected, much much faster but the accuracy drops to around ~70%. I've tried moving stuff around but I just can't figure out why this happens. If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

P.S.
I'm aware that there is an almost identical question already asked on stack overflow but the answer to that question doesn't change anything for my situation, this is why I'm posting this as a separate question. Thank you.

**Edit:** I tried not using `tf.Dataset` but still using my `load_image_and_label` function, the results were again ~90% accuracy, meaning that there is a problem somewhere with `tf.Dataset` pipeline, anyone got any experience with this kind of a problem?

Comment: Why are you shuffling your images during inference (predicting) ?

Comment: I'm not, I've edited that out, I've put that in the question by accident

Comment: Can you set dct_method='INTEGER_ACCURATE' for tf and check- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514897/difference-between-the-return-values-of-pil-image-open-and-tf-image-decode-jpeg

Comment: I tried it, still the same.

Comment: Can you try loading your images in your first approach like you are doing in `load_image_and_label`, to see if it is a problem with `PIL` and `TF` or the `tf.data.Dataset`. The image resizing methods could also be different.

Comment: I wanted to do that before but I get stuck because `file_path` variable is a tensor and I don't know how to extract the String value from it, do you have any suggestions on that front ?

Comment: I've tried that but it causes an error.

Comment: Do you set a batch size when you don't use `tf.data.Dataset`?